# Android animation speed too slow

Tags: android, performance, animation, duration

I am using an animationlistener with INFINITE repeat settings and it is important that every time it loops the onAnimationRepeat function is called.

This all works well with the animattion duration set to ~100ms or higher. Any smaller value I set (e.g. 30ms) still seems to be around 100ms. I tried this on device and on emulator.

I am using an Alphaanimation but i also tried other types of android animations.

Is there a way to make any animation work properly with a duration set around 50ms and faster?

Answer (score 4):

AlphaAnimation is a fairly resource-intensive animation compared to other "sliding" animations.

You may try investigating with [TraceView](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/traceview) to see exactly where it is getting hung up.

I suspect that it is simply the overhead of the animation that is slowing everything down.

Give the TraceView a shot, report back with results and I'll see if I can give further advice.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your hint. AlphaAnimation really seems to be heavier on performance than others. I changed it to ScaleAnimation and now it is slightly better, but still not as reliably fast as I need it. I then created a fakeAnimation class extending Animation doing absolutely nothing, and even then, the animationlistener is not triggered as fast as I set the interval with **.setduration** to.

Comment: Did you try using TraceView to see how long each method takes?  It might be because you are instantiating the Animation/AnimationFactory each time.  It is better performance-wise (though you need to be careful) to use a single controller if you are going to be doing something over and over again with no overlap, and simply restart the Animation each time, rather than creating a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but for people googling around like I am now.

Try adding this into the animation xml:

android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"

Correct me if I'm wrong but i think it works for both Translate and Alpha

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="100%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```